# SQL - create multiple calendars in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a table which calculates multiple calendars depending on the start and end date of a certain row. I have a table which looks like this:

key  Start_date End_date

123.1   1-10-2009   24-12-2009

123.2   1-7-2010    9-2-2011

123.3   1-5-2011    30-10-2011

.........

For each key I want a new row with startdate +1 month until enddate.

For now I have query which works only if my temporary table contains one row, which is:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = (select Start_date from #dim2);

SET DATEFIRST 7;
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
SET LANGUAGE US_ENGLISH;

DECLARE @CutoffDate DATE = (select End_date from #dim2);

CREATE TABLE #dim3
([verwachte_aflossing]      DATE,-- PRIMARY KEY,
 );

INSERT #dim3([verwachte_aflossing] )
SELECT d 
FROM
(
 SELECT d = DATEADD(month, rn-1, @StartDate) 
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(month, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) 
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
   FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
   CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
   ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
 ) AS x
) AS y
```

Does anyone now how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server recursive *cte* is one option to do that

```
WITH CTE as
(
    select [Key], start_date, end_date from table
    union all
    select [Key], dateadd(month,1,start_date) start_date, end_date 
    from cte
    where datediff(month, start_date, end_date) > 0
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```